# nvim: langmap doesn't work with alt?

Tags: terminal, vim, gnome-terminal

I run nvim 0.1.7 in gnome-terminal. I map `a-a` to something and set langmap so that I can use the same shortcut when entering in other language:

```
nnoremap <a-a> :echo 'it works'<cr>
set langmap=фa
```

It doesn't help, `alt-a` works, but `alt-ф` doesn't. Am I using langmap right?

I am aware about `keymap` option, the question is about `langmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like langmap works only for 8bit encodings, not for utf8.

Neovim bug: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2420

Vim bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/297